# How could value be added to an array when there haven't any yet?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This comes from a problem in freeCodeCamp JS course: 'Use Recursion to Create a Countdown'. The code goes like this:

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

When countArray is created, it isn't an array, it just equal to countup (n-1). So how could the value n be pushed into countArray?

Comment: `countup(n - 1);` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

The base case of the recursion creates the array with

```
return [];
```

This is returned to the previous case, which pushes into it and returns the array again with `return countArray;`